# Tesseract Training for a new Language, First Nations, Canada Aboriginal Sans Language not recognized

Tags: fonts, tesseract

I am attempting to convert dictionary to text
we have a new font using a question mark looking character which stands for "catch in throat" called glotto

I have trained using
ubuntu 18.05
training.sh
aboriginal fonts (downloaded new fonts)

everytime I train it fails to recoginze the new language and uses "African (iku) or chr" but does not have a listing for our new language

I need any help

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do and what exactly is going wrong. Specifically, "I have trained using ubuntu 18.05 training.sh aboriginal fonts (downloaded new fonts)" could be expanded to include what command you are actually running, what new fonts you downloaded and where you put them, what version of the tool you are using, etc. If this is an issue with a specific piece of software, you might get better results posting in a forum for that particular software.

Comment: Thank you for your response,  I am attempting to convert a Tiff to text.    the tiff is an image of a dictionary excert to convert to our own language.   we have a font that works for the keyboard. so we can type in our language, we need to convert tiff to text.   I can't find a language code in language.sh file that works IKU fails even though it uses the correct "Aboringal Sans" font name